# Remove multiple commas between two strings

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am having two strings separated by multiple commas. 
**I need to retain only a single comma between the two strings. for example I have as follows**
**var cptCode = G1077,,,,,,,,,,D3456** 
**so after removing multiple commas, I will have like this : var cptCode = G1077,D3456**
**The user can enter 2 commas or 5 commas between the two strings. Maximum number of commas between the two strings will be 10.**
I request the members to let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please take a look at [ask] and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 2):

That's basic JavaScript. It doesn't really even matter how many commas are there, 2 or a million. Just replace them all with a single instance:

```
cptCode = cptCode.replace(/,+/g,',');
```

Where `/,+/g` is a Regular Expression meaning "find a comma (`,`) followed by any further commas (`+`), globally within the string (`/.../g`)." Each match will then be "replaced" with just a single comma (the second parameter).

Comment: Thanks a ton.. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Add them to a list, then join the list.

```
List<String> values = <field>.split( ',' );
String result = String.join( values, ',' );
```

Comment: JavaScript, not Apex. Also, you'd end up with the same commas you had before. The correct version would have been: `<field>.split(',+')`.

Comment: you're right, of course your answer would be simplest.